# Matlab: Function won't calculate for the entire range

Tags: matlab, function

Im trying to plot this function on a given range and it will only calculate the function at one point instead of the entire range.

Here is the code:

```
A0 = -4.29;
A1 = 1.41;
A2 = -11.6;
A3 = 17.1;


h = @(x) (-2* (A2 + x)* pi * A0 * A1.^3)/((A1.^2 * (A2 + x).^2 + pi.^2).^2);
%Plotting Function
x = [0:0.5:25];


figure()
plot(x,h(x));
title('d2y/dx2 Curve');
grid on;
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use element-wise division. Change the `/` into `./`.